# R best subset selection to find (1) what the single best variable is, (2) what the first variable is, and (3) what the last variable is

Tags: r, model-selection

I am trying to analyse this dataset using best subset selection:

[image]

I perform best subset selection using the [R `regsubsets` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaps/versions/3.1/topics/regsubsets) as follows:

```
library(leaps)

best.fit <- leaps::regsubsets(SP.df$Sales ~., data = SP.df, nvmax = 8)
summary(best.fit)
```

[image]

I want to find (1) what the single best variable is, (2) what the first variable is, and (3) what the last variable is.

My understanding is that the best variable is the one with the lowest RSS:

```
res.sum <- summary(best.fit)
best.rss <- which.min(res.sum$rss)
best.rss
```

[image]

So the lowest RSS is the value in index 8, which is 1458.084:

```
res.sum$rss

[1] 2552.244 2043.551 1727.774 1515.913 1462.897 1458.683 1458.189 1458.084
```

But, if I'm not mistaken, the subset selection output above shows that `Price` is the first variable inserted in the model, right? Therefore, the lowest RSS of 1458.084 must belong to `Price`? And, since this is best subset selection, one would expect that the first variable inserted in the model would be the one with the lowest RSS, right? Furthermore, if my understanding so far is correct, then the subset selection output above tells us that the *last* variable inserted in the model is `D`, right? Am I understanding/interpreting this correctly?

Comment: I would assess importance of predictors (by some definition of "importance") based on the decrease of the RSS if a predictor is added to a model containing all other predictors.